# Constructor of subclass acts oddly

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

In the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class first{

    public:
        first(){cout << "FIRST" << endl;}

};


class second: public first{

    public:
        second(){cout << "SECOND" << endl;}

};


int main(){

    second obj();

    return 0;
}
```

Nothing is outputed.When instantiating an object of `second` , both constructors are called, so why is there no output?

Turns out, that if in the main function the command is: `second* pointer = new second();` the output is:

```
First
Second
```

Why does that happen?

Comment: `second obj();` is interpreted as declaration of function with name `obj` that returns object of type `second` and takes no arguments. To create an object use uniform initialization `second obj{};` or simply `second obj;` or `second obj = second();`

Comment: try `first f();` to realize that inheritance isnt the problem

Comment: Use [ES.23: Prefer the {}-initializer syntax](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es23-prefer-the--initializer-syntax) to avoid this problem.